# Problems with convergence of the EM algorithm for a gaussian mixture regression

Tags: regression, panel-data, likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I have been implementing a EM-algorithm for a latent-class regression model, where every individual has a vector of observations.

Currenly, I have the problem that the model does not converge. The log likelihood seems to be increasing up until a certain point, after which the segments 'swap and the likelihood is decreases sharply again.

Plot of $p_s$

[image]

Plot of Log-likelihood. Note that the scale is x1e10.

[image]

My derivation of the algorithm is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq: mixture spec}
    y_{ijt} = x_{{s_i}jt}' \beta_{s_i} + \alpha_{s_i} + \gamma_{ij}  +  \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{equation}

\noindent
where $s_i$ is a latent, unobserved variable that we treat as a stochastic variable with $P[S_i = s] = p_s$ for $s = 1, ..., K$ and $\sum_{s=1}^K p_s = 1$. Mixture models are often estimated with the EM algorithm. This is an iterative algorithm that in the E-step calculates the posterior probabilities $\tilde{p}_s = P[s_i = s | y, \hat{\theta}]$ given the current set of parameter estimates $\theta$ and in the M-step maximises the expected log-likelihood function with respect to the set of parameters $\theta$.

Given this specification we have the following likelihood function:

\begin{multline}
    L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N \sum_{s=1}^K p_s \left(\prod_{j=1}^M \prod_{t=1}^T \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s_i}, \alpha_{s_i}, \gamma_{ij}) \right)  
    \\ = \prod_{i=1}^N \sum_{s=1}^K p_s \left(\prod_{j=1}^M \prod_{t=1}^T 
    \frac{1}{\sigma_{\varepsilon} \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}}\left( y_{ijt} - x_{{s_i}jt}' \beta_{s_i} - \alpha_{s_i} - \gamma_{ij}\right)^{2}\right) \right)
\end{multline}

For the EM algorithm we consider the complete data likelihood function:

\begin{equation}
    L_j(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N  \prod_{s} \left(p_{s} \prod_{j=1}^M \prod_{t=1}^T \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\epsilon}) \right) ^{I(s_i = s)}
\end{equation}

and the subsequent log-complete likelihood:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq: log complete}
    \ell_{j}(\theta)=\log L_{j}(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{s=1}^K I(s_i = s) (\log \: p_s  + \sum_{j=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\log \: \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\epsilon}) \right) )
\end{equation}

In the E-step we calculate:

\begin{equation}
    \pi_{i s} \equiv \mathrm{E}\left[I\left(s_{i}=s\right) \mid y_{ijt}, x_{ijt} \right]=   \frac{  \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\epsilon}) p_{s}}   {\sum_{k=1}^K \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{k}, \alpha_{k}, \gamma_{{k}j}) p_k}
\end{equation}

Substituting this in the log-complete likelihood gives:

\begin{equation}
    \ell_{j}(\theta)=\log L_{j}(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{s=1}^K \pi_{i s} (\log \: p_s  + \sum_{j=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\log \: \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\epsilon}) \right) )
\end{equation}

And the M-step results in maximising:
\begin{equation}
        \max _{p, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \sigma} \left(  \left(\sum_{s=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_{i s} \log p_{s}\right)+\left(\sum_{s=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_{is}  \sum_{j=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^T \log \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\epsilon})\right) \right)
\end{equation}

Solving
\begin{equation}
    max_{p}\left(\sum_{s=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_{i s} \log p_{s}\right) \text { subject to } \sum_{s=1}^{K} p_{s}=1
\end{equation}

yields
\begin{equation}
p_{s}=\frac{1}{i} \sum_{i=1}^{i}\pi_{is}
\end{equation}

For the second part:
\begin{multline}
    \max _{p, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \sigma}  \left(\sum_{s=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_{is}  \sum_{j=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^T \log \phi(y_{ijt}, x_{ijt}; \beta_{s}, \alpha_{s}, \gamma_{ij}, \sigma_{\varepsilon})\right) 
    \\ =  max _{p, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \sigma}  \left(  \sum_{s=1}^{K} \sum_{i=1}^{N}  \pi_{is} \sum_{j=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^T -\frac{1}{2} \log \left( 2 \pi \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2 \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}} \left( y_{ijt} - x_{sjt}' \beta_{s} - \alpha_{s} - \gamma_{ij}\right)^{2} \right)
\end{multline}

And my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import statsmodels.api as sm
from config import Config
import itertools
import pickle
from panel_model import transform_yX


def convert_log_row(row):
    
    new_row = pd.Series(index=row.index, dtype='float64')
    base = 0
    for s in row.index:
        value = row[s]
        basevalue = row[base]
        part1 = value - basevalue
        other_values = row.drop(base)
        diff = other_values - basevalue
        e_diff = np.e ** diff
        part2 = np.log(1 + sum(e_diff))
        pi = np.e ** (part1 - part2)
        
        new_row[s] = pi
    
    return new_row

def eval_log_L(y, X, betas, variances, p_array):
    
    logL = 0
    
    artists = list(X.reset_index()['ARTIST_KEY'].unique())
    segments = list(betas.columns)   
    
    es = pd.DataFrame(index=y.index, columns=betas.columns,data= X.dot(betas).sub(y, axis=0))
    es = es.reset_index()
    
    all_ediff = {}
    
    for a in artists:
        
        e_a = es[es['ARTIST_KEY'] == a]
        e_a = e_a.loc[:, betas.columns]
            
        logpiphi = pd.Series(index=segments, dtype='float64')    
        
        for s in segments:
            logpiphi[s] = eval_phi_ct(e_a[s], variances[s]) + np.log(p_array[s])
        
        logL += logpiphi[0]
        
        sume = 0
        for s in range(1, len(segments)):
            diff = (logpiphi[s] - logpiphi[0])
            try:
                e_pow = np.e **  diff
                all_ediff[(a, s)] = e_pow
            except:
                print('ERROR RAISED FOR ARTIST ' + str(a) + ' FOR SEGMENT ' + str(s))
            if e_pow != float('+inf') and e_pow != float('-inf'):
                # print('NOT inf for ' + str(a) + 'segment' + str(s))
                sume += e_pow
                # print('sume=' + str(sume))
            else:
                pass
                # print('inf for ' + str(a) + 'segment' + str(s))
        
        plus = np.log(1 + sume)
        logL += plus
        
        # print('Artist ' + str(a) + '. Log L = ' + str(logL))
    
    return logL 

def eval_phi_ct(e, var):
    
        return -1 * len(e) * np.log(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)) - (1 / (2 * var)) * sum(e ** 2)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    
    data = read_joined('joined_onlyartistwithmarketing.csv')
    
    #construct data
    genres = [x for x in list(Config.GENRE_MAPPING.values()) if x != 'Other']
    data = data.drop(genres, axis=1)
    data = clean_artist(data)

    
    data = data.drop(['twitter', 'snapchat'], axis=1)
    
    #dict to store the data in
    results = {}
    results['betas'] = {}
    results['variances'] = {}
    results['pi'] = {}
    results['p'] = {}
    results['LogL'] = {}
    results['i'] = {}
    results['resids'] = {}
    results['residsum'] = {}
    results['se'] = {}
    
    
    #perform ac transformation
    y,X = transform_yX(kind= 'ac', data=data)
    y = y.iloc[:, 0]
    
    #get variables, artists and segments
    NO_SEGMENTS = 4
    segments = list(range(NO_SEGMENTS))
    variables = [x for x in data.columns if x not in ['DATE_KEY', 'ARTIST_KEY', 'COUNTRY_CODE', 'ARTIST_NAME','TOTAL_DAILY_STREAMS']]
    artists = list(data['ARTIST_KEY'].unique())
    data = data.set_index(['DATE_KEY', 'ARTIST_KEY', 'COUNTRY_CODE'])
    # Initialise start values for beta and sigma
    betas = pd.DataFrame(index=variables, columns=segments)
    ses = pd.DataFrame(index=variables, columns=segments)
    y2 = data['TOTAL_DAILY_STREAMS']
    X2 = data[variables]
    data = data.reset_index()
    # mod = sm.RLM(y, X, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
    mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
    res = mod.fit() 
    beta_start=res.params
    e = y - X.dot(beta_start)
    
    standard_errors_start = res.bse    
    for s in segments:
        for variable in variables:
            if s == 0:
                betas.loc[variable, s] = beta_start[variable]
            else:
                betas.loc[variable, s] = beta_start[variable] + norm(0, standard_errors_start[variable]).rvs()
    #create empty dataframes
    variances = pd.Series(index=segments, data=res.scale)
    pi_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=artists, columns=segments)
    p_array = pd.Series(index=segments, data=1/ NO_SEGMENTS)
    
    segments_artists = list(itertools.product(segments, artists))
    
    
    for i in range(0, 100): 
        
        print(betas)
        
        results['betas'][i] = betas.copy()
        results['variances'][i] = variances.copy()
        results['se'][i] = ses.copy()
        
        #determine the new p_is
        for s, a in tqdm(segments_artists, position=0, leave=True):
        # for s, a in segments_artists:
            rel_beta = betas[s]
            var = variances[s]
            p = p_array[s]
            rel_data = data[data['ARTIST_KEY'] == a]
            y_a = rel_data['TOTAL_DAILY_STREAMS']
            X_a = rel_data[variables]
            e = y_a - X_a.dot(rel_beta)
            log_p_phi =  -1 * len(e) * np.log(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)) - (1 / (2 * var)) * sum(e ** 2) + np.log(p)
            phi_eval = log_p_phi
            pi_matrix.loc[a, s] = phi_eval 
        
        
        for j in range(len(pi_matrix)):
            row = pi_matrix.iloc[j, :]
            newrow = convert_log_row(row)
            pi_matrix.iloc[j,:] = newrow
        results['pi'][i] = pi_matrix.copy()
        
        #calculate the new S number of p's
        p_array = pi_matrix.mean()
        print(p_array)
        results['p'][i] = p_array.copy()
        
        #calculate new betas and sigmas
        
        #together method
        Xconcat = np.kron(np.identity(NO_SEGMENTS), X)
        yconcat = pd.concat([y.to_frame()] * NO_SEGMENTS, ignore_index=True)[0]
        empty_weights = pd.DataFrame(index=data.set_index(['DATE_KEY', 'ARTIST_KEY', 'COUNTRY_CODE']).index, dtype='float64').reset_index()
        pi_matrix_mod = pi_matrix.reset_index().rename(columns={'index' : 'ARTIST_KEY'})
        weights = pd.merge(empty_weights, pi_matrix_mod, how='left', on=['ARTIST_KEY'])
        weights = list(weights.set_index(['DATE_KEY', 'ARTIST_KEY', 'COUNTRY_CODE']).stack())
        
        mod = sm.WLS(yconcat, Xconcat, weights=weights)
        res = mod.fit()
        b = list(res.params)
        v = res.scale
        se = res.bse
        results['resids'][i] = res.resid
        results['residsum'][i] = res.resid.apply(lambda x : x ** 2).sum()
        
        
        for s in segments:
            # print(s)
            betas[s] = b[12* s: 12 * s + 12]
            ses[s] = se[12* s: 12 * s + 12]
            variances[s] = v
        
        
    resids = pd.Series(data = list(results['residsum'].values()))
    resids.plot()
    Log_likelihood = pd.Series(data = list(results['LogL'].values()))
    Log_likelihood.plot()
    p_matrices = list(results['p'].values())
    P = pd.DataFrame(columns = p_matrices[0].index)
    for k in range(len(p_matrices)):
        P = P.append(p_matrices[k], ignore_index=True)
    P.plot()
```

I perform all the log transformations for calculation LogL and the $pi_as$ in order to prevent numerical errors.

Comment: This is very detailed and clear, but it's also a lot to read through. I have one suggestion -- if you're not already, generate some simulated data from your model, and fit your model to that simulated data but with all of the (nuisance?) parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ fixed (during the likelihood maximization step) to their known values (e.g. 0). If that works, start turning on estimation of the extra parameters until it breaks again, helping to isolate the problem if it's related to some typo.

Comment: It looks like you assume all $\epsilon_{ijk}$ to be i.i.d. with variance $\sigma_\epsilon$, which is not said explicitly (you might want to add that), also at some point there is a switch from $\gamma_{s_ij}$ to $\gamma_{ij}$. Other than that I don't see anything wrong with the formulae. I can't debug your code, but I'd agree that the likelihood should increase and not look as it does. In your place I'd try to look at what exactly happens (tracking all parameters) when the likelihood goes down, and which equation does it, to find the issue.

Comment: Ah, @ChristianHennig observation that in this model the variance of each sample is independent of the sample $s_i$ might break by above recommendation unless either $\sigma$ are allowed to vary per latent class or the fixed value of $\alpha$ differs per class, so that the distribution of the different latent classes are distinguishable.

Comment: Apologies, this is a typo, it should be $\gamma_{ij}$ everywhere.
I indeed assume the variances to be equal over the classes. Before I did not have this assumption, but then it completely broke the model and I needed to do the estimation of the betas in one fit() call. Might this be the issue? That the equal variances cause identification issues?

Comment: "Might this be the issue? That the equal variances cause identification issues?" If anything I'd expect a model to be better identified with fewer parameters, i.e., equal variances.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe that is the issue either, and was referring only to my recommended debugging test in the first comment -- where taking what I wrote literally (alpha, beta, gamma all fixed) plus the fact that there is one global sigma would mean that the distributions of each mixture in the debugging test would be identical, and of course at least one parameter must differ between the components. That's not an issue for the actual model you're fitting to your real data.